# Error use of uninitialized value

Tags: json, perl

So I made this small script today in perl.

For some reason it doesn't seem to be downloading anything, and an error keeps popping up saying

```
Use of uninitialized value $id in concatenation (.) or string at room.pl line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $id in concatenation (.) or string at room.pl line 18.
```

Could someone help me fix this code?

Also is using File::Path okay? and this is the json http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/rooms.json

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path;

mkpath "rooms/";

use JSON;
use LWP::Simple qw(mirror);

open FILE, 'rooms.json' or die "Could not open file inputfile: $!";
sysread(FILE, my $result, -s FILE);
close FILE or die "Could not close file: $!"; 
my $json = decode_json($result);

foreach $item ($json) {
my $id = $item->{room_key};
mirror "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/rooms/$id.swf" => "rooms/$id.swf";
}
```

Comment: Can you add a print $id before the call to mirror and post its output here?

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin or prntscr.com.  The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions.  Therefore, future readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Comment: Okay I will, I'm sorry. I never knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach my $item ...` at line 16 should do the trick!

As its a hash-ref you have to loop over it this way:

```
...
foreach my $item (sort keys %$json) {
        my $id = $json->{$item}->{room_key};
        print $id . "\n";
        #mirror "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/rooms/$id.swf" => "rooms/$id.swf";
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately It's still the same :(

Comment: Also I suppose `$json` is an array reference? Then you have to loop like this: `foreach my $item (@$json) {}`

Comment: Yes it is an array reference but for some reason it won't work and it keeps saying that it is not an array reference.

Comment: You can use `Data::Dumper` to print the whole structure or just `print $json`. What does it say?

Comment: You do realize that `$item` and  `$id` are **always** the same value.